# Puppeteer: Cannot find element loaded by Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, puppeteer

I've been using Puppeteer to scrape some websites, and it works well when the element I need is in the DOM; however I can't get it to work when the element is loaded via Javascript. E.g. please see my code below. More specifically, the page.waitForSelector always triggers a timeout error. I've tried a page.screenshot and the resulting image does show a fully loaded page, which contains this .evTextFont element.

How can I modify this code to successfully retrieve the .evTextFont element?

I've tried both Puppeteer versions 1.11 and 1.17, but am getting the same problem for both

Thanks a lot

Adapted from [here](https://dev.to/napolux/how-to-scrap-that-web-page-with-nodejs-and-puppeteer-811)

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const URL = 'https://www.paintbar.com.au/events-1/moments-in-moonlight';

puppeteer.launch({ headless: true, args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'] }).then(async browser => {
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({width: 1200, height: 600})
    await page.goto(URL, {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});
    await page.waitForSelector('.evTextFont');
    await page.addScriptTag({url: 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js'});
    // await page.screenshot({ path: './image.jpg', type: 'jpeg' });

    const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
        try {
            var data = [];

            $('.evTextFont').each(function() {
                const title = $(this).text();
                data.push({
                    'title' : title,
                });
            });
            return data;

        } catch(err) {
            console.log(err.toString());
        }
    });

    await browser.close();

    for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        console.log('Data: ' + result[i].title);
    }

    process.exit();
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because the event you're looking for is shown inside of an `iframe` element, from another site, so you need to find that iframe first and then do operation on it.

```
await page.goto(URL, {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});

// Looking for the iframe with the event
const frame = (await page.frames()).find(f => f.url().includes("events.wix.com"));

// Then do work as before, but on that frame
await frame.waitForSelector('.evTextFont');
await frame.addScriptTag({url: 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js'});

const result = await frame.evaluate(() => {...})
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Vaviloff! That works perfectly and I learned something new